# Vokoscreen area recording problem

Tags: screencast

I'm having problems trying to make area recordings with Vokoscreen 2.0.0-2 in Ubuntu 14.04, the center marker is showing in the video. Is there any way to make area recordings without this center marker appears in the video !?

Below is a capture from a video with the problem:
[image]

Comment: It might be an issue with 2.0.  I have 1.9, and it doesn't have that problem.

Comment: I updated to the 2.0 from 1.9 trying to solve that problem, but without success...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved in the update 2.0.13, that in this moment only available from [Debian repositories](http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/v/vokoscreen/).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, this bug was fixed in vokoscreen 2.0.13.

You can download a .deb package for newer versions here: http://ftp.slackware.com/pub/ubuntu/pool/universe/v/vokoscreen/

e.g. vokoscreen 2.1.0 .deb for 64-bit Ubuntu is: http://ftp.slackware.com/pub/ubuntu/pool/universe/v/vokoscreen/vokoscreen_2.1.0-1_amd64.deb

It depends on vlc, so installation for me looked like:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
sudo dpkg -i vokoscreen_2.1.0-1_amd64.deb
```

If you get a dependency error, you might need a `sudo apt-get -f install`, then rerun the dpkg command.